# CSS Sound bar behind input slider

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem. I created the following HTML page:

```css
.audio-control {
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

.fa-play, .fa-pause {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#progress-bar {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sound-bars {
    flex: 1;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.audio-bars {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0px 3px;
    height: 30px;
    align-items: end;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #153725;
}




/* SOUND BAR ANIMATION */
.animate-bars {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     width: 100%;
     height: 20px;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
}
 .animate-bars div {
     flex: 1 0 auto;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 -2px;
     background-color: #90416b;
     animation: animate-bar 300ms linear infinite alternate;
     transform-origin: bottom;
     opacity: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:first-child {
     margin-left: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(1) {
     animation-duration: 701ms;
     animation-delay: 333ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(2) {
     animation-duration: 569ms;
     animation-delay: 199ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(3) {
     animation-duration: 677ms;
     animation-delay: 279ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(4) {
     animation-duration: 781ms;
     animation-delay: 152ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(5) {
     animation-duration: 516ms;
     animation-delay: 194ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(6) {
     animation-duration: 541ms;
     animation-delay: 21ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(7) {
     animation-duration: 387ms;
     animation-delay: 352ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(8) {
     animation-duration: 691ms;
     animation-delay: 168ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(9) {
     animation-duration: 612ms;
     animation-delay: 74ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(10) {
     animation-duration: 781ms;
     animation-delay: 168ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(11) {
     animation-duration: 587ms;
     animation-delay: 426ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(12) {
     animation-duration: 375ms;
     animation-delay: 418ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(13) {
     animation-duration: 400ms;
     animation-delay: 236ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(14) {
     animation-duration: 645ms;
     animation-delay: 81ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(15) {
     animation-duration: 379ms;
     animation-delay: 195ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(16) {
     animation-duration: 561ms;
     animation-delay: 424ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(17) {
     animation-duration: 384ms;
     animation-delay: 31ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(18) {
     animation-duration: 704ms;
     animation-delay: 265ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(19) {
     animation-duration: 464ms;
     animation-delay: 88ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(20) {
     animation-duration: 589ms;
     animation-delay: 447ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(21) {
     animation-duration: 713ms;
     animation-delay: 207ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(22) {
     animation-duration: 782ms;
     animation-delay: 194ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(23) {
     animation-duration: 610ms;
     animation-delay: 493ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(24) {
     animation-duration: 371ms;
     animation-delay: 249ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(25) {
     animation-duration: 481ms;
     animation-delay: 74ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(26) {
     animation-duration: 746ms;
     animation-delay: 65ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(27) {
     animation-duration: 382ms;
     animation-delay: 165ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(28) {
     animation-duration: 592ms;
     animation-delay: 71ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(29) {
     animation-duration: 600ms;
     animation-delay: 274ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(30) {
     animation-duration: 401ms;
     animation-delay: 174ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(31) {
     animation-duration: 606ms;
     animation-delay: 271ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(32) {
     animation-duration: 515ms;
     animation-delay: 363ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(33) {
     animation-duration: 405ms;
     animation-delay: 122ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(34) {
     animation-duration: 448ms;
     animation-delay: 274ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(35) {
     animation-duration: 439ms;
     animation-delay: 246ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(36) {
     animation-duration: 429ms;
     animation-delay: 470ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(37) {
     animation-duration: 565ms;
     animation-delay: 287ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(38) {
     animation-duration: 462ms;
     animation-delay: 103ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(39) {
     animation-duration: 590ms;
     animation-delay: 442ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(40) {
     animation-duration: 444ms;
     animation-delay: 181ms;
}
 .animate-bars-center div {
     transform-origin: center;
}
 @keyframes animate-bar {
     0% {
         transform: scaleY(0);
         opacity: 0.8;
    }
     100% {
         transform: scaleY(100%);
         opacity: 0.4;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-control">
    <button id="btnPlay" (click)="onPlayClick()" value="play"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
    <span id="current-time" class="time">0:00</span>

    <!-- Animate from bottom -->
    <div class="audio-bars">
        <div id="sound-bars">
            <div class="animate-bars">
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="range" id="progress-bar" max="93" value="0" (input)="onProgressChange()">
    </div>

    <span id="duration" class="time">1:33</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that the soundbar and the progress bar are being placed next to each other, while I want them to overlap. The sound-bar must be placed behind the progress-bar and the sound-bar must be as wide as the progress-bar. This page also needs to be responsive, so changing the page width, must maintain the relation between the 2 bars. Here is the result I have now:
[image]

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Please let your SCSS compile to CSS, and add that to the first code snippet - otherwise, this currently doesn't show any "bars" at all, and with _just_ the range input, it is hard to tell what would need adjusting to what width exactly now.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know I could just convert it. I have updated my snippet!!

Comment: Absolutely positioning the range input would probably make the most sense, I guess. If `.audio-control` is supposed to be simply full-width at all times, that might require an additional inline container to wrap bars and range input.

Comment: I have added an additional container arround them and made the sound-bar `absolute`, but I need to add `width: 100%`, but that makes it go out the page bounds?

Comment: I would rather position the input field absolute, so that the bars can actually determine the necessary width.

Comment: Then the input field goes out of the page?

Comment: Is the container inline/inline-block, and relative positioned (so that it can serve as reference point for the absolutely positioned descendant)?

Comment: I updated my snippet with the code I have now!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/19jmwrsy/ - if you need to adjust the input further, then use `calc` for its width to compensate for tiny margins or similar.

Comment: Yessss!!! If you can put that in an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would position the range input field absolute, so that the underlying bars themselves determine the width. (They go over the full available width here, but this way it should work in other situations as well, like if `.audio-bars` got `flex:50%` instead or something.)

If the input goes a bit to far to the right, then try and use `width: calc(100% - ...)` to compensate for margins etc.

```css
.audio-control {
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

.fa-play, .fa-pause {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#progress-bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sound-bars {
    flex: 1;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.audio-bars {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0px 3px;
    height: 30px;
    align-items: end;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #153725;
}




/* SOUND BAR ANIMATION */
.animate-bars {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     width: 100%;
     height: 20px;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
}
 .animate-bars div {
     flex: 1 0 auto;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 -2px;
     background-color: #90416b;
     animation: animate-bar 300ms linear infinite alternate;
     transform-origin: bottom;
     opacity: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:first-child {
     margin-left: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(1) {
     animation-duration: 701ms;
     animation-delay: 333ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(2) {
     animation-duration: 569ms;
     animation-delay: 199ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(3) {
     animation-duration: 677ms;
     animation-delay: 279ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(4) {
     animation-duration: 781ms;
     animation-delay: 152ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(5) {
     animation-duration: 516ms;
     animation-delay: 194ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(6) {
     animation-duration: 541ms;
     animation-delay: 21ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(7) {
     animation-duration: 387ms;
     animation-delay: 352ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(8) {
     animation-duration: 691ms;
     animation-delay: 168ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(9) {
     animation-duration: 612ms;
     animation-delay: 74ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(10) {
     animation-duration: 781ms;
     animation-delay: 168ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(11) {
     animation-duration: 587ms;
     animation-delay: 426ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(12) {
     animation-duration: 375ms;
     animation-delay: 418ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(13) {
     animation-duration: 400ms;
     animation-delay: 236ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(14) {
     animation-duration: 645ms;
     animation-delay: 81ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(15) {
     animation-duration: 379ms;
     animation-delay: 195ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(16) {
     animation-duration: 561ms;
     animation-delay: 424ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(17) {
     animation-duration: 384ms;
     animation-delay: 31ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(18) {
     animation-duration: 704ms;
     animation-delay: 265ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(19) {
     animation-duration: 464ms;
     animation-delay: 88ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(20) {
     animation-duration: 589ms;
     animation-delay: 447ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(21) {
     animation-duration: 713ms;
     animation-delay: 207ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(22) {
     animation-duration: 782ms;
     animation-delay: 194ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(23) {
     animation-duration: 610ms;
     animation-delay: 493ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(24) {
     animation-duration: 371ms;
     animation-delay: 249ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(25) {
     animation-duration: 481ms;
     animation-delay: 74ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(26) {
     animation-duration: 746ms;
     animation-delay: 65ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(27) {
     animation-duration: 382ms;
     animation-delay: 165ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(28) {
     animation-duration: 592ms;
     animation-delay: 71ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(29) {
     animation-duration: 600ms;
     animation-delay: 274ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(30) {
     animation-duration: 401ms;
     animation-delay: 174ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(31) {
     animation-duration: 606ms;
     animation-delay: 271ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(32) {
     animation-duration: 515ms;
     animation-delay: 363ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(33) {
     animation-duration: 405ms;
     animation-delay: 122ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(34) {
     animation-duration: 448ms;
     animation-delay: 274ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(35) {
     animation-duration: 439ms;
     animation-delay: 246ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(36) {
     animation-duration: 429ms;
     animation-delay: 470ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(37) {
     animation-duration: 565ms;
     animation-delay: 287ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(38) {
     animation-duration: 462ms;
     animation-delay: 103ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(39) {
     animation-duration: 590ms;
     animation-delay: 442ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(40) {
     animation-duration: 444ms;
     animation-delay: 181ms;
}
 .animate-bars-center div {
     transform-origin: center;
}
 @keyframes animate-bar {
     0% {
         transform: scaleY(0);
         opacity: 0.8;
    }
     100% {
         transform: scaleY(100%);
         opacity: 0.4;
    }
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<div class="audio-control">
    <button id="btnPlay" (click)="onPlayClick()" value="play"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
    <span id="current-time" class="time">0:00</span>

    <!-- Animate from bottom -->
    <div class="audio-bars">
        <div id="sound-bars">
            <div class="animate-bars">
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="range" id="progress-bar" max="93" value="0" (input)="onProgressChange()">
    </div>

    <span id="duration" class="time">1:33</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Overlapping elements in Flexbox is a bit besides the point of Flexbox. The solution I would suggest is CSS grid, where you can specify a 1x1 responsive grid, then affix these elements to the single node that you just created.

However, in Flexbox as in normal css, you are able to add a `position:absolute;` to the parent elements and enforce positioning, then float the soundbars behind with a `position:relative`. The rest of the problem should just be general styling.

```css
.audio-control {
    display: flex;
    width:300px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

.fa-play, .fa-pause {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#progress-bar {
    flex: 1;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width:100%;
}

#sound-bars {
    flex: 1;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.audio-bars {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0px 3px;
    height: 30px;
    align-items: end;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #153725;
}




/* SOUND BAR ANIMATION */
.animate-bars {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     width: 100%;
     height: 20px;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
}
 .animate-bars div {
     flex: 1 0 auto;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 -2px;
     background-color: #90416b;
     animation: animate-bar 300ms linear infinite alternate;
     transform-origin: bottom;
     opacity: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:first-child {
     margin-left: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(1) {
     animation-duration: 701ms;
     animation-delay: 333ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(2) {
     animation-duration: 569ms;
     animation-delay: 199ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(3) {
     animation-duration: 677ms;
     animation-delay: 279ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(4) {
     animation-duration: 781ms;
     animation-delay: 152ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(5) {
     animation-duration: 516ms;
     animation-delay: 194ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(6) {
     animation-duration: 541ms;
     animation-delay: 21ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(7) {
     animation-duration: 387ms;
     animation-delay: 352ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(8) {
     animation-duration: 691ms;
     animation-delay: 168ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(9) {
     animation-duration: 612ms;
     animation-delay: 74ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(10) {
     animation-duration: 781ms;
     animation-delay: 168ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(11) {
     animation-duration: 587ms;
     animation-delay: 426ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(12) {
     animation-duration: 375ms;
     animation-delay: 418ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(13) {
     animation-duration: 400ms;
     animation-delay: 236ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(14) {
     animation-duration: 645ms;
     animation-delay: 81ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(15) {
     animation-duration: 379ms;
     animation-delay: 195ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(16) {
     animation-duration: 561ms;
     animation-delay: 424ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(17) {
     animation-duration: 384ms;
     animation-delay: 31ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(18) {
     animation-duration: 704ms;
     animation-delay: 265ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(19) {
     animation-duration: 464ms;
     animation-delay: 88ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(20) {
     animation-duration: 589ms;
     animation-delay: 447ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(21) {
     animation-duration: 713ms;
     animation-delay: 207ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(22) {
     animation-duration: 782ms;
     animation-delay: 194ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(23) {
     animation-duration: 610ms;
     animation-delay: 493ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(24) {
     animation-duration: 371ms;
     animation-delay: 249ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(25) {
     animation-duration: 481ms;
     animation-delay: 74ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(26) {
     animation-duration: 746ms;
     animation-delay: 65ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(27) {
     animation-duration: 382ms;
     animation-delay: 165ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(28) {
     animation-duration: 592ms;
     animation-delay: 71ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(29) {
     animation-duration: 600ms;
     animation-delay: 274ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(30) {
     animation-duration: 401ms;
     animation-delay: 174ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(31) {
     animation-duration: 606ms;
     animation-delay: 271ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(32) {
     animation-duration: 515ms;
     animation-delay: 363ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(33) {
     animation-duration: 405ms;
     animation-delay: 122ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(34) {
     animation-duration: 448ms;
     animation-delay: 274ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(35) {
     animation-duration: 439ms;
     animation-delay: 246ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(36) {
     animation-duration: 429ms;
     animation-delay: 470ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(37) {
     animation-duration: 565ms;
     animation-delay: 287ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(38) {
     animation-duration: 462ms;
     animation-delay: 103ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(39) {
     animation-duration: 590ms;
     animation-delay: 442ms;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(40) {
     animation-duration: 444ms;
     animation-delay: 181ms;
}
 .animate-bars-center div {
     transform-origin: center;
}
 @keyframes animate-bar {
     0% {
         transform: scaleY(0);
         opacity: 0.8;
    }
     100% {
         transform: scaleY(100%);
         opacity: 0.4;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-control">
    <button id="btnPlay" (click)="onPlayClick()" value="play"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
    <span id="current-time" class="time">0:00</span>

    <!-- Animate from bottom -->
    <div class="audio-bars">
        <div id="sound-bars">
            <div class="animate-bars">
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="range" id="progress-bar" max="93" value="0" (input)="onProgressChange()">
    </div>

    <span id="duration" class="time">1:33</span>
</div>
```